# Tracking what triggered an update to an IObservable in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm working with IObservable for the first time, trying to debug some code that was written a while ago. I mostly follow what it's doing, but the issue I'm having is that we have a method OnChanged that is subscribed to this object, triggering when something about the object is changed, but I'm struggling to track down where the change that causes the method to go off is coming from. Can anyone suggest any ways to do find this information out?

Comment: I don’t quite understand why you’re struggling with this. If you have access to the source code, why don’t you just look at the code that emits values? I think you need to provide some more information because it’s not obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's **by far not a good** solution but it should work

```
public void OnChanged(object property, [CallerFilePath] string file = null, [CallerLineNumber] int (not sure) lineNumber = null)
{
    // Body
}
```

With these attributes you should get the file and line number

Comment: I would like to see how this actually works with an observable.